# Static Files Don't Load When Running Django Openshift Application Locally

Tags: python, django, openshift

I'm developing a Django app in Openshift, but if I want to run my application locally `[localhost:8000]` the application doesn't load static files but my HTML templates are loaded and displayed perfectly.

Comment: Usually that is an indicator that your settings for the static assets might be incorrect. Could you update the question with your current settings for `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`? Further, if you are running the app with `manage.py runserver` then also make sure to follow [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/static-files/) if necessary.

Comment: @sthzg I know it and looked for them but i can't the solution for my problem 
or else can you say how to look for staticfiles in the application `[myapp]` to write inside `settings.py`

Comment: What server are you running locally? The Django development server? On OpenShift if static files are in correct location it will automatically host them using Apache/mod_wsgi. Locally, if not using Django development server, you would need to configure the server to host them yourself, through server configuration or by using Whitenoise Dango middleware.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have no problem when running my project in openshift. but, while running the project locally it can't find the static files _ like css,js, images etc_

Comment: The question was 'what server are you running locally?'. I am saying that on OpenShift things are handled for you automatically. They may not be when run locally and why am asking you what server you are running locally.

Comment: I'm using default django development which runs when the command `python manage.py runserver` is runned

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide more details or share code, particularly the templates code that work fine and the code in them that doesnt load the static files.
Most basic issues could be you are missing the right static file configuration. Or simply missing the template tag `{% load staticfiles %}`.

Try: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: Briefly what happening here is, when i commit the code to **Openshift** and open the page the static files are loaded and they are displayed correctly.
but when running locally _(In my PC)_ it doesn't find my static files `[Windows]`

Answer (score 0):

So I experienced a similar issue. As mentioned by utkarshmail2052, if you look at the Django docs [serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) you'll see the following:

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files. If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver
>   will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True...

So my quick fix was confirming that **DEBUG = True** in my settings.py file on my local machine. Now when you run `python manage.py runserver` django should automatically server the static files on your localhost.

Just make sure that DEBUG is false before you deploy your app.